# Duplicate identifier with ionic2 + Firebase 3

Tags: typescript, firebase, ionic2, typescript-typings

I have a problem with the configuration of ionic2 + Firebase 3.

I have executed the following (as i see in a tutorial) to install Firebase and Typings:

- npm install firebase --save
- npm install -g typings
- typings install --save firebase

But when i make **ionic serve**, i see the following conflicts:

```
typescript: node_modules/firebase/firebase.d.ts, line: 405           
Duplicate identifier 'export='. 
typescript: typings/modules/firebase/index.d.ts, line: 498
Duplicate identifier 'export='.
```

I have googeled very similar problems, but i cant solve it.

I don't understand the problem, the **tsconfig.json** looks like:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es2015"
    ],
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "target": "es5"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "atom": {
    "rewriteTsconfig": false
  }
}
```

Can anyone help me out of this, please?

Comment: The recent `firebase` releases include TypeScript `.d.ts` files, so you no longer need the typings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the latest release of Ionic 2: RC0 (they released RC1 a couple of days ago) Ionic is no longer working with typings, they moved to @types.

So you do `npm install @types/package_name` instead of `typings install package_name`

Usually the `@types` ecosystem is strong and you wouldn't need anything else, but there are a few issues on how Ionic 2RC0 and Firebase 3 work together, you can [check this guide](https://javebratt.com/ionic2rc0-firebase-js-sdk/) for all the workarounds :)

Comment: Thank you very much, you totally answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

Just go into the node_modules/firebase directory .

And remove the firebase.d.ts - definitions file.

and also remove typings - using npm uninstall typings.